# Request merging of the [eventqueue] family

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

Please to merge on SO

- [eventqueue](/questions/tagged/eventqueue) at 27 posts
- [event-queue](/questions/tagged/event-queue) at 7 posts
- [awt-eventqueue](/questions/tagged/awt-eventqueue) at 14 posts

to

- [eventqueue](/questions/tagged/eventqueue)

Thank you.

Comment: "requirest" = "requirement" + "request"!

Comment: @gnat one of points..., reason why I'm outspoken expert in English language :-)

Comment: I think `event-queue` makes more sense than `eventqueue`..

Comment: @Seth doesn't matter, event-queue or eventqueue ...

Comment: Why don't you just edit the questions as think appropriate?  This isn't exactly such a crushing number of questions that they require a mod's intervention.

Comment: @blahdiblah maybe you are right, true is that (original idea) I don't want to "bothering" with tags removing, I'd have to wait(ng) one_two days